# VHDL/Verilog related programming forums?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog, systemc

Hardware design with VHDL or Verilog is more like programming nowadays. However, I see SO members are not so actively talking about VHDL/Verilog programming.

Is there any forum dealing with hardware design with Verilog/VHDL/SystemVerilog or SystemC?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Logic Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45270/logic-design) was closed because of too little attention. It's now reopened, but interest remains low.

Comment: Seems to be closed again. I would just use https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ - there are [1400 Verilog questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verilog).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a summary:

- [comp.arch.fpga](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.arch.fpga/)
- [comp.lang.verilog](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.verilog/)
- [comp.lang.vhdl](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.vhdl/)
- [EDA Board](http://www.edaboard.com/)
- [Altera Forum](http://www.alteraforum.com/)
- [Cadence Community Forum](http://www.cadence.com/community/forums/)
- [Mentor Verification Academy (SystemVerilog User's Group, OVM/UVM)](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/all?sort_by=created)
- [Xilinx Forum](http://forums.xilinx.com/)
- [Verification Guild](http://verificationguild.com/)
- [EETop](http://bbs.eetop.cn/) (in Chinese, Google translate is your friend)
- [Sonsivri](http://www.sonsivri.to/forum/index.php) (private forum)
- [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com) (there are a number of groups here)

Comment: Mentor's SystemVerilog forum is now [here].(https://forum.verificationacademy.com/forum/verification-methodology-discussion-forum/systemverilog-and-other-languages-forum)

Comment: Actually, it move again https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/all?sort_by=created

Answer (score 4):

IRC: ##verilog, ##vhdl, ##fpga on irc.freenode.net

Netnews: comp.arch.fpga (http://groups.google.com/group/comp.arch.fpga/topics)

Answer (score 4):

comp.lang.vhdl

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.vhdl/

I haven't actively read it in a couple years, but I recall it being a great source, with some very knowledgeable and helpful people.  Looking at it now it appears to be getting a lot of spam, which is unfortunate.

Comment: My feeling is that the glorious days of this usenet group are past. Lots of spam, lots of flame wars. Still some very knowledgable people, though.

Answer (score 4):

[Xilinx](http://forums.xilinx.com/) and Altera FPGA forums deal with different aspects of using Verilog/VHDL for FPGAs.

Answer (score 3):

The [Verification Guild](http://verificationguild.com) forum deals with hardware design **verification** with Verilog/VHDL/SystemVerilog.

Update:
Another forum I discovered recently is: [edaboard.com](http://www.edaboard.com)

Comment: edaboard.com is in general very good, but in my humble opinion has a somewhat high density of low quality questions (but quite amusing)

Answer (score 1):

Verilog News Group:
http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-verilog/

Answer (score 1):

From the [FPGA|DSP|embedded]related.com pages: [www.fpgarelated.com/](http://www.fpgarelated.com/)