# What does \ mean while calling a function in C?

Tags: c, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I was looking some code, and saw that it used a \ to separate lines while calling a function, does this mean something? Or is it just to be more readable?

```
        function(\
        lets_say_this_a_long_attribute, \
        and_this_is_another_attribute_with_a_long_name_or_operations, \
        attribute);
```

Comment: Line continuation. Is it part of a `#define` macro?

Comment: Some people are even using it outside of `#define`, totally missing the point..

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6281389/7852589) may be of your interest

Comment: @FredLarson It's not inside a define macro, it's just used in a normal function.

Comment: @RealReza Thank you! I hadn't seen that question and it answers my question.

Comment: See C11 [§5.11.1.2 Translation phases](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) and phase 2.  It simply means that the following newline and the backslash are removed before the preprocessor gets going on the code.  It's pointless; you sometimes find it in code by tyros or newbies, less often in code by experienced programmers.  See also GCC [Slightly looser rules on escaping newlines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Escaped-Newlines.html#Escaped-Newlines).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the C Standard ([5.1.1.2 Translation phases](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2))

> 2. Each instance of a backslash character () immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>      form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical
>      source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A
>      source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which
>      shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any
>      such splicing takes place.

For example these physical lines

```
i\
n\
t\
 x;
```

form the logical line

```
int x;
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    i\
n\
t\
 x = 10;

    p\
r\
i\
n\
t\
f
    ( "%d\n", 
    x );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
10
```

This technique is used for writing macros like for example #define.

Comment: And it happens so early in the processing that you can split comment start and end symbols with backslash-newline pairs.

Comment: @machine_1: code obfuscators routinely do it, chopping lines at N characters long, and simply putting a backslash at the end of one line and continuing onto the next.  But you're right — sane programmers with no devious intent do not do this.  Note that trigraphs are processed before Phase 2; they cannot be split across lines (but `??/` might appear at the end of a line to indicate a backslash-newline pair).

Comment: Good answer. I'm just missing a single point: The fact that any `#define` is terminated by the first logical newline character following it, which makes writing of multiline macros impossible without joining several physical lines into a single logical line using the `\-<newline>` sequence. And that is also the only valid use in programs that are meant for human consumption.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica It can be useful to break complicated `#if` expressions over multiple lines as well.