# How do I split test case name into 2 lines

Tags: c++, googletest

I want to split the gtest case name into 2 line as the name exceeds more than 75 character per line.

Consider a sample test case.

```
TEST_F(ServerCN#3Test,
       ServerCN#3ConnectionCreateReturnErrorNo87WhenInvalidconnectionConnectionParameterPassed) {
    char * ip = xx.xx.xx.xx;
        int port = 1111
    error = class::ConnectionCreate(ip,port);
    EXPECT_EQ(error, 87);
}
```

Is it possible to make it to 75 character per line, like this

```
TEST_F(ServerCN#3Test,
       ServerCN#3ConnectionCreateReturnErrorNo87When
       InvalidconnectionConnectionParameterPassed) {
    char * ip = xx.xx.xx.xx;
        int port = 1111
    error = class::ConnectionCreate(ip,port);
    EXPECT_EQ(error, 87);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281368/multi-line-define-directives that's the closest workaround I could think of. Otherwise, C++ identifiers cannot include whitespaces, so you cannot have tab alignment like in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You are already in macro-world, so you can use one more to concatenate two parts of the name:

```
#define TEST_F(NAME) HELLO WORLD NAME
#define LONG_NAME(A,B) A##B

TEST_F(LONG_NAME(Foo,
          Bar))
```

[expands to](https://godbolt.org/z/9hrhToEK7):

```
HELLO WORLD FooBar
```